# case when value contains text or symbols (>, <)

Tags: postgresql, case-when

I'm trying to write case when statement for a particular field that has three patterns of values, which are normal numeric values (i.e. 0.6, 12.1), numeric values with symbols (i.e. > 14.0, < 1.2) and texts (i.e. canceled).

I'm trying to keep the numeric values (i.e. if 0.6 then leave it as 0.6), convert numeric values with symbols to numeric (i.e. if > 14.0 then convert it to 14.0), and exclude text values. Here is some example of the data, 'original' is the value I have currently and 'I want' is the desired output of case when.

```
row_id   val (original)   val(I want)
---------------------------------------
  1           1.2            1.2
  2          > 0.4           0.4 
  3         Canceled         null 
  4          < 1.6           1.6
  5           22.0           22.0
  6         not done         null
```

For the symbols (> or <) I could hardcode each distinct `val` (i.e. `case when val = '> 0.2' then '0.2'`) but I'm hoping to learn if there is a more general way to approach it without writing when statement for each `val`.

For the text values, I tried `isnumeric()` but it doesn't work, it isn't even recognized as a function. I haven' found successful solution in PostgreSQL from other posts, would there be a way to classify text values and exclude it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [trim and replace functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-string.html) to eliminate the characters < and > and leading and trailing spaces. Then a regular expression to validate the remaining characters form a legitimate numeric value. So something like:

```
 with test (rnum, val) as 
      ( values (1,'   1.2    ')   
             , (2,'  > .4   ')   
             , (3,' Canceled ')   
             , (4,'  < 1.6   ')   
             , (5,'   22.0   ')   
             , (6,' not done ')
       )
select rnum, val  
     , case when res ~ '^([0-9]+\.?|^\.?)[0-9]*$'  then res else null end res 
  from (select rnum, val, trim(replace(replace(val,'<',''),'>','')) res
          from test
        ) r;
```

See additional [example here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=ff1c6d7ddeacab8e7ea0f910323b4cfa)

Admittedly this can be done with a single regular expression, but in order to deal with the additional 'valid' non numeric characters and spaces the expression gets complicated fast. And I am not sure the performance would be any better. Regular expressions tend to be slow, trunc and replace are pretty fast.